# Deploy selected release in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

This is how my colleague set up the stages

[image]

here the release of changes

[image]

The question is, how can i deploy to PROD (let say only project C - Release 194 and 196), without A, accidentally pushed together to PROD (because it hasnt approve to go to PROD)?

Thank you,
your helps really appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you wish to take a release of anything to a specific environment, and you have the appropriate approval permissions, you can do the following:

1. Click the link for the Release-### you wish to deploy
2. The pipeline will appear, and in the ribbon above, click the Deploy dropdown. Depending on how your pipeline is configured, you'll have the ability to deploy to a single or to multiple environments. Choose where you'd like it to go.

Your question wasn't completely clear, so I've answered as best I can, but it seems from what I read that you might be using a single pipeline to manage deployment of multiple projects? Am I correct? If so, you might wish to look at creating a pipeline for each project - The only way I know what is deployed where in your question is to look at the annotations you added to the right. Separate release definitions would give you better clarity into that. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi @waitingforguacamole, after digesting seems like the single pipeline configuration causing this, deploying release-196 to PROD, will causing release-193 brought together to PROD env. Thank you for the answer, really helpful. I will try to observe configuration to create a pipeline in each project.

Comment: I think that depends on the pipeline settings. A pipeline can be configured so that, if multiple releases are stacked up on an environment, it can cancel any existing releases and only retain the most recent as active. This is reasonable so long as each release "rolls up" previous release functionality/fixes.